# how to get the value of the lines when hovering the mouse on highchart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graph, charts, highcharts

I have a graph with three lines. I want to display below the graph the values of the lines that were hovered over by the mouse.

http://jsfiddle.net/pntuz40L/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            series: [{
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
               
                 lineColor: 'red',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you can achieve that by using the `point.mouseOver()` or `series.mouseOver()` event:

Here is an example of getting information about the point's series and values, and showing them in the div below the chart:

```
   plotOptions: {
     series: {
       point: {
         events: {
           mouseOver() {
             var div = document.getElementById('info');
             div.innerHTML = "Series: " + this.series.name + "</br>" + "x: " + this.x + "</br>" + "y: " + this.y;

             return div.innerHTML
           }
         }
       }
     }
   },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xvymqb3n/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver